# How to alias Into<Option<T>> in Rust?

Tags: rust

It's a common pattern to use `Into<Option<T>>` for optional arguments in Rust, as it allows the function to be called with either `None` or some `t: T` which is user friendly. However I find this type annotation a bit verbose, so I want to alias this pattern.

Until [true trait aliasing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/trait-alias.html) is stabilized in Rust, there seems to be a hack for aliasing traits: https://www.worthe-it.co.za/blog/2017-01-15-aliasing-traits-in-rust.html.

How can I use this in my case? I tried the following code:

```rust
pub trait Optional<T>:Into<Option<T>>{}
impl<T> Optional<T> for T where T: Into<Option<T>>{}

fn main(){
    add(3.0, None);
    add(1.0, 2.0);
}

fn add<T: Optional<f64>>(a: f64, b: T) -> f64 {
    let b = match b.into() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => 0.0
    };

    a + b
}
```

However the compiler says:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Option<_>: Optional<f64>` is not satisfied
 --> test.rs:5:14
  |
5 |     add(3.0, None);
  |              ^^^^ the trait `Optional<f64>` is not implemented for `Option<_>`
...
9 | fn add<T: Optional<f64>>(a: f64, b: T) -> f64 {
  |           ------------- required by this bound in `add`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

So clearly the hack isn't working, as the compiler can't detect that any `f64` or `None` should implement this interface.

How can I fix this alias so that it compiles correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two type parameters involved here. `T` is the type of the optional value, so `f64` in your example. So

```
impl<T> Optional<T> for T where T: Into<Option<T>>{}
```

only implements `Optional<f64> for f64`. But you want to implement it for other types too, so you need to use a different type parameter. Try

```
impl<T, U> Optional<T> for U where U: Into<Option<T>> {}
```

Now finally this can implement `Optional<f64>` (`T=f64`) for `f64` (`U=f64`), `Option<f64>` (`U=Option<f64>`) and any other type that is `Into<Option<T>>`.

… I should probably write it as

```
impl<ValueT, ConvertibleT> Optional<ValueT> for ConvertibleT
    where ConvertibleT: Into<Option<ValueT>>
```

because there is nothing special about the letter `T` and generics with multiple parameters deserve proper naming of their parameters just like one usually does for function arguments.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c28a3f16aa51e194dea5e7268efb739))

Comment: Wait I'm confused. If `T` is the type of the optional value, what is `U`? For example it makes sense for me to read the first example as "implement optionality for T as long as T is convertible into an Option". Am I interpreting this wrongly? How would I read your second example?

Comment: @Migwell You implement optionality for `U` as long as `U` is convertible to `Option<T>`. Because for the one `T` ultimately intersting for `add`, `f64`, there is multiple types that are `Into<Option<T=f64>>`. And `U` iterates over them. `T` can't, `T` is already bound to the inner value type.

Comment: Ohhh so this is adding flexibility for types that are convertible to the *inner* type, of which `None` is one that the compiler was originally complaining about. I get it now, thanks!

Comment: @Migwell, by *inner* type I'd understand the actual value, which is `f64` in the `add` function. `None` isn't that. So I'd rather say it is adding flexibility for the *outer* type, the one that can be converted to `Option<f64>`, or whatever other `Option<Inner>` you'll need. Because that's what `None` is—`Option<Something>` for whatever `Something` is inferred.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure if this will cover all use cases of your alias, but I just implemented your trait directly for `Option<T>` and it compiled.

```
impl<T> Optional<T> for T where T: Into<Option<T>>{}
impl<T> Optional<T> for Option<T>{}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63a07f88333bf1025194b90b57bfa056)

```
pub trait Optional<T>:Into<Option<T>>{}
impl<T> Optional<T> for T where T: Into<Option<T>>{}
impl<T> Optional<T> for Option<T>{}

fn main(){
    println!("{}",add(3.0, None)); // 3
    println!("{}",add(1.0, 2.0));  // 3
}

fn add<T: Optional<f64>>(a: f64, b: T) -> f64 {
    let b = match b.into() {
        Some(b) => b,
        None => 0.0
    };

    a + b
}
```

This works for me even with a function like this and passing `add_opt(None, None)`.

```
fn add_opt<A: Optional<i32>, B: Optional<i32>>(a: A, b: B) -> i32 {
    match (a.into(), b.into()) {
        (Some(a), Some(b)) => a + b,
        (None, Some(b)) => b,
        (Some(a), None) => a,
        (None, None) => 0,
    }
}
```

I couldn't manage to add mixing of convertable types, e.g. passing `i8` and `Option<i16>` both of which are implicitly converted into `Option<i32>`

Comment: Hmm but the whole point is that `Optional<T>` should be automatically implemented for anything that implements `Into<Option<T>>`, which both `None` and `3.0` do.

Comment: It might be because by passing just `None` compiler isn't sure that it comes from `Option<f64>`, not any other option like `Option<String>`